# Rocket.Chat ignores "ROOT_URL"

Tags: node.js, meteor, rocket.chat

I downloaded the new Rocket.Chat 6.4.4 from tar.gz file (installing it as a service without docker)I  and set up the service with the below environment variables:
ROOT_URL="https://full.domain.name/" PORT=3001

The service is running but the web server shows three dots and trying to fetch files from
http://localhost:3001/**meteor**/dynamic-import/fetch

I tried it with the following versions with the same results:
6.4.1
6.4.2
6.4.3

On version 4.6.3 the same configuration works as expected.

Comment: Is there any entry in the changelogs mentioning `ROOT_URL`? It's two major versions apart and there might be big changes.

Comment: I don't know if it is mentioned in the changelog. It has an open issue on the official repository.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change the value in db. The value is set up at first launch and is set as source after that.

```
db.rocketchat_settings.update(
  {
    "_id": "Site_Url"
  }, {
    $set: {
      value: "<YOUR NEW URL>"
    }
  }
)
```

Src : https://www.ryadel.com/en/rocket-chat-change-root_url-site-url-rocketchat/?utm_content=cmp-true